# Why navigate is not working properly via buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm having a small issue this didn't happen on previous updates of `react-router-dom` however I'm now using V6 and I don't understand why this is happening cause it really does not make sense to me.

So when I click on Home while being in another path

[image]

it should take me to the HOME path right and it does however when I click on it AGAIN right after that it takes me back to the previous path before HOME and that does not make any sense at all.

This is what I have:

```
//Initialize
    const navigate = useNavigate("");

    const goHome = () => {
      navigate("/Home");
    };
    
//Render
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}>
         <StyledIconButton size="small" edge="start" color="inherit" aria-label="menu" sx={{ mr: 2 }} onClick = {goHome}>
            <HomeIcon/>
            <Typography  variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}> HOME </Typography>
          </StyledIconButton>
    </Box>
```

Is a simple box wrapper from mui with an iconbutton, icon, typo and that's it. I'll be making a Sandbox.

**UPDATE**

Sandbox: [Code-SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-https-t4w3x?file=/src/App.js)

**UPDATE 2**

Sandbox gave me the following:

[image]

Comment: I see no overt issue with this specific code/logic. Can you share a more complete code example? Is it possible for you to create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: yeah I'm on that give me a minute.

Comment: have you tried using useRouter instead?

Comment: useRouter? no sorry I always have use history which now is navigate. Before it was something like this: 

`const history = useHistory("");`
`const goHome = () => { history.push("/Inicio"); };`

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-https-t4w3x?file=/src/App.js) that's weird the above one is working try again.

Comment: that's weird idk what's going on then, cause I'm saving it.

Comment: I just open it seems to be working

Comment: Ok, seems the CSB finally got all the code there, and it took me a bit to realize you must also have some media-query breakpoints since much of your UI is hidden on narrower viewports (*such as that of the codesandbox*). After fixing the `useNavigate` hook import, I manually navigated to "/CoolEarth" and click the home button, and go home (*`"/Home"`*), and after clicking the home button again, nothing happens, the app stays on `"/Home"`.

Comment: How you fix it ? cause I'm getting the following *Attaching image to description*

Comment: In `AppToolBar` you have `import { BrowserRouter as useNavigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";`.... so the `useNavigate` in the code isn't the hook, but the router component. It should be `import { useNavigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";` so you are actually importing the hook.

Comment: Yeah I notice after a while that definitely helped me.  So I assume that BrowserRouter should only be used on the "start app"

Comment: Yes, you need only one router wrapping the entire app to provide a routing context.